# Where should the sensitive information be stored?

Tags: ios, core-data, plist, nsuserdefaults, nsdocumentdirectory

Is it fair to store sensitive data in NSUserDefaults ?

I have read that this is a big issue because, NSUserDefaults are stored in plist in binary format, with no encryption, and is stored in your app’s directory. This means that any user, even the “noobiest” one, can tinker with your NSUserDefaults with 5 minutes of their time.

Any user can edit, see, share, move and whatever they please with it. Jailbreak users can simply install iFile, navigate to your app directory, play with the file, and move on with their day.

So, what is the best way to store user sensitive information ? Should I use Coredata and store encrypted information ?

Comment: Depending on how sensitive information you want to store is it may be better not to store it at all. What kind of info do you want to store?

For small amounts of data Keychain may do(AFAIK it's almost the same protection as NSUserDefaults on JB devices), for some of info you may need to encrypt the whole store and/or individual data attributes.

Comment: User credentials, User email, User address etc...

Comment: Take a look at the Keychain API.

Comment: Can you tell me difference when should use plist and when userdefaults ?

Comment: UserDefaults are meant to store user settings and not the whole app data, so if you want to store some data like text document you should use plist different from UserDefaults one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store user credentials I'd use Keychain (also it would help if server-side could accept some kind of hash instead of plain password). I'd say that users with JB probably know what they are doing and can protect themselves too, so I think it's not so big deal that Keychain is much easier to hack with JB than without it.

To store things like address etc I'd use transformable attributes if you use CoreData ([This post](http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/2012/07/securing-your-core-data-with-transformable-attributes/) may help).

Additional protection from iOS side can be file protection attribs(if user has passcode set up).

UserDefaults are not meant to store sensitive info since it's basically "plain text".

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp.html) document. Although there is not a lot of information it is still a good point for start. Also you might find it useful to dig around [examples and guides](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Topics&topic=Security) from Apple (you must be logged in). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

**NSUserDefaults vs Sensitive** information is ideally supposed to be stored in **keychain**. But there are reasons you should avoid it in case you don't want the features of **keychain** like -

1. Once your app is uninstalled keychain doesn't remove the info (key, value). So just make sure you have no problem in piling up the keychain although there is no misuse of the info left stored in keychain. info from NSUser defaults is removed as soon as app is uninstalled.
2. With iCloud keychain information is shared across devices having access to credentials. Although they are very much your devices but not every time user uses same app across the device so why impart credentials.
3. On devices like MAC keychain access cause ask-permission popup.